# Port Forwarding - Verizon Router - Blocked - Default Policy

Tags: router

I am trying to open port 8443 on a verizon router. I have created the following rule:

IP: 192.168.1.222
Rule: (HTTPS Secondary) TCP Any->8433 over WAN connection type: Broadband Connection (Ethernet/COAX)

I have other rules that work okay - example:
192.168.1.222 (HTTP) -> TCP Any->80 over wan: broadband connection (Ethernet/COAX)

In my security log I keep seeing the following:
Jun 22 10:57:31 2017    Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy
TCP 199.83.243.62:53433->PUB.LIC.IP.ADDRESS:8443 on eth1

Comment: Please ask on SuperUser, home networking is off-topic for this board.

Comment: This was not home networking. We are exposing a webserver on our business network. What is the difference between NetworkEngineering and SuperUser?

Comment: You mentioned a verizon router. Is that a small business router provided by a carrier? If so, then it is off-topic. Please refer to the rules of this stack.

Comment: Will do - Sorry for the confusion. New to this stack.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to some static NAT we had setup. The requests were being translated to the public ip / nat'd address.

We had to modify the static nat to add tcp 8443 to the list so that requests on this port go to the internal IP.